# Es posible modificar un elemento con CSS cuando el evento se registra en otro?

Tags: css, selector, shadow

Tengo este input

```
              <div class="input-group mb-3">

                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text border-0 bg-white input-icon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                </div>
                <Input
                  span='border-0 bg-white shadow-sm'
                  className='shadow-sm border-0 bg-white input-shadow'
                  placeholder='&#xf000; Search'
                  name='email'
                  type='email'
                  required={true}
                  error={errors.email}
                  value={values.email || ''}
                />
              </div>
```

Y se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero, es que al posarme sobre un input, este "venga al frente", lo hago asi:

```
.input-shadow{
  &:focus{ 
    box-shadow: 0 9px 16px rgba(50,50,93,.1), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
    transform: translateY(-2px);
   }
 }
```

Y lo que sucede es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Bueno, mi idea es que el icono tambien se levante y se "muevan juntos" el `span`y el `Input`, me explico?

Probé con esto pero no funciona:

```
.input-shadow{
  &:focus{ 
    box-shadow: 0 9px 16px rgba(50,50,93,.1), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
    transform: translateY(-2px);

    .input-icon{
        box-shadow: 0 9px 16px rgba(50,50,93,.1), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
        transform: translateY(-2px);
     } 
   }
 }
```

> Lo quiero ver asi: (para que se vea asi le puse las propiedades a los elementos en el inspector del navegador, quisiera saber como pasarsela con css/scss)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es posible, deberías usar la pseudo-clase de CSS `:focus-within`, mirate esta docu https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: Gracias @LauraZ era exactamente lo que buscaba. .input-group{
  &:focus-within{}} arregló todo. Si queres respondelo asi voto y cierro :)